# Downgrade Microsoft Surface RT to Windows 8.0

Tags: microsoft-surface, windows-rt

I want to downgrade my Surface RT (1st generation) from Windows RT 8.1 back to its original Windows RT 8.0. I attempted to reset it (which reinstalled Windows) and am still left with Windows RT 8.1. I also checked Microsoft support for a recovery image and they no longer provide an image for Windows RT 8.0. Any other ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? As I understand it, the Surface RT only comes with Windows RT. Windows RT is a tablet variant of Windows 8 designed for the ARMv7 architecture of the Surface RT hardware.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Fixed the typo and clarified. Thanks.

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage). Not sure if it'll give you an RT 8.0 or RT 8.1 image though.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Once I put in my SN I only get "Surface RT - Windows RT 8.1"

Comment: Yea, I thought that might happen. Why do you want to downgrade anyway? RT 8.0 stopped receiving updates a long time ago and is probably not a good platform to run on. Do you have a specific requirement to run RT 8.0?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I've had driver issues and am unable to uninstall the particular FW update.

Comment: You don't be able to.